# Calculate the Stop time for stepper motor after the stop command was initiated

Tags: motordriver

Currently we have a stepper motor  with load configured in Open loop so there is no feedback as such to determine the angle which motor makes due to interia after giving the stop command.

Is there a way to find the angle that motor rotates until it gets stopped after stop command was initiated using the open loop system.